# Finding three independent solutions for the system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on this assignment. Not sure how to begin.

Let $\begin {bmatrix}2&1&1\\ 0&2&3\\ 0&0&2\end {bmatrix} = A$ as part of the system $Ax=x'$. Find three independent solutions for the system.

The system has eigenvalue 2 with multiplicity 3.You need to develop a way to extend methods for dealing with repeated eigenvalues from multiplicity 2 to multiplicity 3. Also, you will need to justify this method, following a similar derivation to that of eigenvalues for a two equation system with a multiplicity of 2. Be sure to verify that the solutions are linearly independent.

Comment: What are the methods you have for eigenvalues with multiplicity 2?

Answer (score 3):

For the first eigenvalue, we can write: $[A-2I]v_1 = 0$.

This leads to:

$$\begin {bmatrix}0&1&1\\ 0&0&3\\ 0&0&0\end {bmatrix}v_1=\begin {bmatrix}0\\0\\0 \end {bmatrix}$$

This leads to eigenvector of: $v_1 = (1,0,0)$.

For the next, repeated, eigenvalue, we can form the generalized eigenvector: $[A - 2I]v_2 = v_1$.

This leads to:

$$\begin {bmatrix}0&1&1\\ 0&0&3\\ 0&0&0\end {bmatrix} v_2=\begin {bmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end {bmatrix}$$

This results in an eigenvector of: $v_2 = (0,1,0)$.

We can try repeating this process again, so, for the next, repeated, eigenvalue, we can form the generalized eigenvector: $[A - 2I]v_3 = v_2$.

$$\begin {bmatrix}0&1&1\\ 0&0&3\\ 0&0&0\end {bmatrix} v_3=\begin {bmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end {bmatrix}$$

This results in an eigenvector of: $\displaystyle v_3 = (0,-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$.

Note this was called the bottom-up method, but there are other ways to approach it, like the adjoint method or top-down method and others. For example, sometimes the bottom-up method does not work and you have to resort to the top-down.

Now, you need to show that these $v_i$ are linearly independent, but I suppose you know how to do that.

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti...great *demonstration* with explanation of your process... ;-)

Comment: I completely agree...extremely much so. If it keeps up, I'm afraid it's going to make the site appear to cater to the more "elite", serving some users rather than the OPs the site purports to welcome. It's all the more reason I'm increasing my support for users who seem to *care* about what, and how they're communicating to those seeking help here.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of your explanation. You made this problem a lot easier than it could have been.